# Symfony, Twig. An advanced way to connect styles and scripts for a page

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

The essence of the problem is that the Twig templates of my project are divided into small parts (modules - I'll call them that), and it is assumed that for each module there will be its own **CSS** and **JS** files that will be connected to the page directly from this fragment:

```
{# ui-button.twig #}
<button class="ui-button">
    {{ icon }} {{ text }}
</button>

{# include resources: #}
{% do add_resource('ui-button') %}
```

This approach is necessary so that I can freely combine fragments with each other at any nesting level, and so that my **JS** and **CSS** are always connected correctly.

I also have my function for Twig, which takes the name of the fragment and based on it gets the path for the asset function and adds it to arrays for js and css files, which I later planned to use to generate a set to connect the scripts and styles I need:

```php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension {
    protected $scripts = [];
    protected $styles  = [];

    public function getFunctions() {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_resources', [$this, 'get_resources']),
            new TwigFunction('add_resouce', [$this, 'add_resouce']),
        ];
    }

    public get_resources ($type) {
        if ($type == 'js')
            return $this->$scripts;

        if ($type == 'css')
            return $this->$styles;
    }

    public add_resouce ($resourse) {
        $css_file = '\/bundle\/' . $resourse . '.css';
        $js_file = '\/bundle\/' . $resourse . '.js';

        if (!is_array($js_file, $this->get_resources('js')))
            $this->$scripts[] = $js_file;

        if (!is_array($css_file, $this->get_resources('css')))
            $this->$styles[] = $css_file;
    }
}
```

I use this data in this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    {% for resource in get_resources('css') %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(resource) }}">
    {% endfor %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock body %}

    {% for resource in get_resources('js') %}
        <script src="{{ asset(resource) }}"></script>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

This solution works well for my **JS** files, but it is completely useless for **CSS**. I get a complete list of all **JS** files, and a completely empty **CSS** array. I know that this is affected by the order of calling the `add_resource` function when processing templates. I tried different ways to get around this and implement the idea, but so far nothing has worked out and now it seems to me that it is impossible to implement it the way I intended.

*Still, is there any way to implement my idea?*

I can't remember exactly which methods I tried, because there were a lot of them, and each was a failure. One of my attempts: I tried to achieve the desired behavior using `embed`, `block`, `use` and combined these structures in different ways. I tried to apply my own method to these attempts, but I failed again. . . :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you use `if (!is_array($js_file, $this->get_resources('js')))`, it should bei `in_array`. you also access properties wrong, instead of just `$this->js_files` you write `$this->$js_files` (extra `$`). These are definitely errors, that might hinder functionality. (you also don't prevent duplicates ;o/) but since you already solved your problem ...